# Excel VBA – Insert Username when cell is changed

Tags: excel, vba

I found some code on this site that I think will solve my issue however when I add it to my workbook and make a change to a cell in the specified column nothing happens. I would like to see if anyone would be able to tell me where I went wrong. What I need it to do is to add the UserName and a TimeStamp in the corresponding cells when a cell in changed in column X (Reviewed by CAT Project). I have put this code into my personal workbook but I dont know if that would be an issue? Also I will need it to work on any worksheet without specifying the name. Here is the code I am using:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim ThisRow As Long ' make sure to declare all the variables and appropiate types
ThisRow = Target.Row

'protect Header row from any changes
If (ThisRow = 2) Then

       Application.EnableEvents = False
       Application.Undo
       Application.EnableEvents = True
       MsgBox "Header Row is Protected."
       Exit Sub

End If


If Cells(2, Target.Column) = "Reviewed by CAT Project" Then

    Dim sOld As String, sNew As String
    sNew = Target.Value 'capture new value

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Undo
    End With

    sOld = Target.Value 'capture old value
    Target.Value = sNew 'reset new value

    If sOld <> sNew Then

        ' time stamp corresponding to cell's last update
        Range("Z" & ThisRow).Value = Now
        ' Windows level UserName | Application level UserName
        Range("Y" & ThisRow).Value = Environ("username")
        Range("Y:Z").EntireColumn.AutoFit

    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The code needs to be in the relevant sheet module. Right-click the sheet tab, View Code and paste the code. Seems to work for me.

Comment: How is the second part of your code ever supposed to run? You're have it test against row 2, but the first part of your code will `Exit Sub` if anything happens there. Also, that method of protection is... unconventional. Why not just lock the cells with the built in feature?

Comment: @dwirony - the second bit only checks what's in row 2 of whichever column has been changed.

Comment: @SJR Hmmm you're right :) I was trying to recreate the excel file and couldn't because of that first portion haha.

Comment: Well now that that's out of the way, I cannot recreate the issue - code works fine. Looks like @SJR is right - it needs to be placed in the correct module.

Comment: Ok, so I have the code on the Sheet1(Sheet1) within my personal workbook. Then I have the code also in Module2 but still nothing is happening. Is it an issue that im trying to put it in my personal workbook?

Comment: Nevermind! I had it looking at the wrong row. So once I put it in my Sheet1 everything is working! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posted code works **if**:

1. Row 2 is setup **before** the code is entered.
2. The code is placed in the **worksheet code area**

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

Macros must be enabled for this to work!